# One locked test case is showing Runtime error

Tags: python

> Given two integers m & n, calculate and return their multiplication
>   using recursion. You can only use subtraction and addition for your
>   calculation. No other operators are allowed.

```
def mult(m,n):
    if(n==0) or (m==0):
        return 0
    if(m==1):
        return n
    y=mult(m,n-1)
    return m+y

m=int(input())
n=int(input())
y=mult(m,n)
print(y)
```

```
Runtime Error
Traceback (most recent call last): File Main.py , line 17, in <module> y=mult(m,n) File Main.py , line 8, in mult y=mult(m,n-1) File Main.py , line 8, in mult y=mult(m,n-1) File Main.py , line 8, in mult y=mult(m,n-1) File Main.py , line 8, in mult y=mult(m,n-1) File Main.py , line 8, in mult y=mult(m,n-1) File Main.py , line 8, in mult y=mult(m,n-1)
```

Comment: Please include the complete traceback in the question.

Comment: Seems to be working fine on the few examples I tried. Can you add the complete stack trace as mentioned before?

Comment: @rdas Please see now.

Comment: Running smoothly on my Jupyter. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: looks like a typical stack overflow. See linked question

Comment: @Sultan Actually It is on 'Coding Ninjas'. The test cases are locked. While submission one test case is showing this error.